# How to find a predicted number in the multiple linear regression model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

The Question asked me to find the predicted number of passengers for the average ship

I've calculated out the β using matrix operations and the lm function in R to estimate the model. But how to calculate a predicted number for the average ship? Thanks

```
cship <- read.csv("C:/Users/Yuxi Liu/Desktop/cruise_ship.dat.csv")
colnames(cship)=c("ShipName","CruiseLine","Age","Tonnage","passengers","Length","Cabins","pdensity","crew")
cship_model = lm(passengers ~ Age + Tonnage + Length, data = cship)
coef(cship_model)
n = nrow(cship)
p = length(coef(cship_model))
X = cbind(rep(1, n), cship$Age, cship$Tonnage, cship$Length)
y = cship$passengers

t(X) %*% X
t(X) %*% y

(beta_hat = solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y)

cship_model = lm(passengers ~ Age + Tonnage + Length, data = cship)
cship_model
```

Comment: You would need to use predict(chsip_model, df_for_average_ship) with the numbers corresponding to the "average ship" in a data frame with matching colnames.

Comment: So do I need to create another lm for cship and average ship?

Comment: No, you just need to create a data frame with the variables containing the values that you want. Let's say that you "average ship" has age = 3, Tonnage = 10, Length = 5.
Create a data.frame(age = 3,Tonnage = 10, Length = 5). Then, use predict in the following way predict(model you created, data frame you created)

Comment: Besides, rather use the assignment operator `<-` and the `=` only within functions, e.g. `cship_model <- lm(passengers ~ Age + Tonnage + Length, data=cship)`.